# How to deal large select with PHP (array, loop or casual)

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, select, html-select

I have a dilemma with large select boxes on the website. If I have a select box that contains more than 300 options, should I use array, loop or just add each option?

I have to use the for loop function to specify later whether the user has this option selected or not (checking with MySQLi database).

I care about the speed of the code.

**Option 1** - Casual code:

```
<optgroup label='{$lang['c_010']}'>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[0]}' ".($g_interests_row_0 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[0]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[1]}' ".($g_interests_row_1 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[1]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[2]}' ".($g_interests_row_2 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[2]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[3]}' ".($g_interests_row_3 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[3]}/option>
    <option $p_2_t data-subtext='{$lang['c_015']}' disabled></option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[4]}' ".($g_interests_row_4 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[4]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[5]}' ".($g_interests_row_5 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[5]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[6]}' ".($g_interests_row_6 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[6]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[7]}' ".($g_interests_row_7 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[7]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[8]}' ".($g_interests_row_8 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[8]}/option>
    <option $p_2_t data-subtext='{$lang['c_021']}' disabled></option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[9]}' ".($g_interests_row_9 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[9]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[10]}' ".($g_interests_row_10 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[10]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[11]}' ".($g_interests_row_11 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[11]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[12]}' ".($g_interests_row_12 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[12]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[13]}' ".($g_interests_row_13 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[13]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[14]}' ".($g_interests_row_14 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[14]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[15]}' ".($g_interests_row_15 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[15]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[16]}' ".($g_interests_row_16 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[16]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[17]}' ".($g_interests_row_17 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[17]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[18]}' ".($g_interests_row_18 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[18]}/option>
    <option $p_2_t data-subtext='{$lang['c_033']}' disabled></option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[19]}' ".($g_interests_row_19 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[19]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[20]}' ".($g_interests_row_20 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[20]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[21]}' ".($g_interests_row_21 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[21]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[22]}' ".($g_interests_row_22 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[22]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[23]}' ".($g_interests_row_23 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[23]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[24]}' ".($g_interests_row_24 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[24]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[25]}' ".($g_interests_row_25 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[25]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[26]}' ".($g_interests_row_26 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[26]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[27]}' ".($g_interests_row_27 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[27]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[28]}' ".($g_interests_row_28 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[28]}/option>
    <option $p_2_t data-subtext='{$lang['c_044']}' disabled></option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[29]}' ".($g_interests_row_29 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[29]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[30]}' ".($g_interests_row_30 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[30]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[31]}' ".($g_interests_row_31 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[31]}/option>
      <option value='{$i_array_value[32]}' ".($g_interests_row_32 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[32]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[33]}' ".($g_interests_row_33 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[33]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[34]}' ".($g_interests_row_34 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[34]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[35]}' ".($g_interests_row_35 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[35]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[36]}' ".($g_interests_row_36 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[36]}/option>
  <option value='{$i_array_value[37]}' ".($g_interests_row_37 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[37]}/option>
</optgroup>
```

**Option 2** - For loop:

```
  for ($j = 0; $j < 367; $j++) {

    $interests_rows = 'g_interests_row_'.$j;
    $demographics_rows = 'g_demographics_row_'.$j;

    $$interests_rows = $db->QueryGetNumRows("$modules_rows_count FIND_IN_SET('".$i_array_value[$j]."', interests)");
    $$demographics_rows = $db->QueryGetNumRows("$modules_rows_count FIND_IN_SET('".$d_array_value[$j]."', demographics)");


    if ($j == 0) {
      echo "<optgroup label='{$lang['c_010']}'>";
    } elseif ($j <= 4) {
      echo $am_sh_di_1;
    } elseif ($j == 5) {
      echo "<option $p_2_t data-subtext='{$lang['c_015']}' disabled></option>";
    } elseif ($j <= 8) {
      echo $am_sh_di_1;
    } elseif ($j <= 10) {
      echo $am_sh_di_2;
    } elseif ($j == 11) {
      echo "<option $p_2_t data-subtext='{$lang['c_021']}' disabled></option>";
    } elseif ($j <= 14) {
      echo $am_sh_di_1;
    } elseif ($j <= 22) {
      echo $am_sh_di_2;
    } elseif ($j == 23) {
      echo "<option $p_2_t data-subtext='{$lang['c_033']}' disabled></option>";
    } elseif ($j <= 33) {
      echo $am_sh_di_1;
    } elseif ($j == 34) {
      echo "<option $p_2_t data-subtext='{$lang['c_044']}' disabled></option>";
    } elseif ($j <= 38) {
      echo $am_sh_di_1;
    } elseif ($j <= 43) {
      echo $am_sh_di_2;
    } elseif ($j == 44) {
      echo '</optgroup>';
    }

    if ($j >= count($d_array_value)) {
      $r_interests = ${"g_interests_row_".($j - count($d_array_value)).""};
    } else {
      $r_demographics = ${"g_demographics_row_$j"};
    }

  }
```

**Option 3** - Array (which is almost the same as Option 1):

```
$test = array(
  "<optgroup label='{$lang['c_010']}'>",
  array(
    "<option value='{$i_array_value[0]}' ".($g_interests_row_0 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[0]}/option>",
    "<option value='{$i_array_value[1]}' ".($g_interests_row_1 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[1]}/option>",
    "<option value='{$i_array_value[2]}' ".($g_interests_row_2 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[2]}/option>",
    "<option value='{$i_array_value[3]}' ".($g_interests_row_3 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[3]}/option>",
    array(
      "<option $p_2_t data-subtext='{$lang['c_015']}' disabled></option>",
      array(
        "<option value='{$i_array_value[4]}' ".($g_interests_row_0 == 1 ? 'selected' : '').">{$i_array_name[4]}/option>",
        ...
      )
    )
  )
)
```

How I should do it?

Comment: imagine how user will look for value in such list

Comment: If you care about the speed of the code, do some benchmarking. you should also consider how maintainable the code will be, and what kind of user experience you will be creating with your 300-odd item select box.

Comment: For this kind of large amount of choices consider the use of the autocomplete field with jqueryui https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Variable variables generally indicate a suboptimal data storage design.  Definitely iterate array data with smart math and conditional processes.

Comment: You may want to look at something like the [Select2](https://select2.org/) or [jQuery Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugins to add auto-complete and searchability functionality to your select elements.